# Consultas relaciones eloquent laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5, tengo una tabla productos y una tabla usuarios. La tabla productos esta relacionada con usuarios,en mis modelos tengo relacionado estas tablas, quiero enviar los productos correspondientes  al usuario a un perfil publico.

¿Cómo puedo generar esta consulta en mi controlador StoreController?

He revisado la documentación de relaciones con eloquent, pero lo que he intentado no me ha funcionado, espero me puedan ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

```
<?php

namespace laravel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Producto extends Model
{


        public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User::class');
    }
    protected $table='productos';
    protected $primaryKey='idProducto';
    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $fillable =[
        'idSubcategoria',
        'id',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'imagen',
        'stock',
        'costo_unitario',
        'Unidad_de_medida',

    ];      



}



<?php

namespace laravel;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{



       public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Producto::class');
    }
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}






  public function user(Request $request,$name)
     { 
        $productos = Producto::all();
        $user =User::select()
        ->where('name','=',$name)
        ->first();
        return view("store.user",compact('user','productos'));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando `with`

```
$user_productos = User::with('productos')->where('name', $name)->get();
```

Tambien se puede hacer la unión manualmente:

```
$user_productos = User::leftjoin('productos', 'productos.id', '=', 'user.id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya estas trabajando con las relaciones de Eloquent, entonces haz uso de *eager loading* y después del método `whereId()` para solo mostrar los datos del usuario en cuestión.

Al inicio de tu `StoreController.php` importa el nombre de la clase donde se encuentra tu modelo `User`

```
use App\User;
```

Posterior dentro de tu método `user()` escribe lo siguiente

```
    $data = User::with('productos')->whereId(5)->get();
```

O si vas a filtrar por nombre, entonces haz lo siguiente

```
    $data = User::with('productos')->where('name', $name)->get();
```

Dentro del método `eager loading` paso como argumento el nombre del método `productos` el cual declaré en la clase  del modelo `User`

Aquí [puedes consultar de eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)